# What is better - "es würde sein" or "es wäre"

Tags: grammar

My German friend told me that in speech, either one makes sense:

> Es würde „cool“ sein!
>
> Es wäre „cool.“

But which one is proper German in order to say something like "It would be cool!"

Additionally, preferably from the perspective of a native speaker, which one would be more common and more acceptable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verbs `sein` and `haben` are preferably conjugated using non-composited forms. In this case

> Es wäre cool.

is clearly preferable.

Comment: this is correct. But i have something to add: using "würde", you can create the conjunctive for almost everything, even if there is a natural conjunctive. this is correct, too, but somethings it's not the finest way..

Comment: @christian.s That both are valid is something, the OP has already said so in his question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference is the implied likelihood and your personal stance toward "Es".

**Es wäre cool** is more likely to happen than **Es würde cool sein**

The "stance" can be explained with a example

When you were just told that the other person will do something for you (maybe something that puts a burden on them) then you can choose:

**Es wäre cool**: polite way of accepting such an offer

**Es würde cool sein**: even more polite. OR: implies that you are  not comfortable with the dimension (you have the feeling that you are asking for too much)

In the end it kind of depends on the way you say it and the context it is said in.

Comment: Just to add: With *sein* *wäre* is also more likely to happen simply because it's shorter, clear (unlike something like *ich editierte* which could be mistaken for past tense) and very frequent, so one doesn't forget the existence of this word (unlike *buk* for *backte*)... and I'm not sure how polite you can make a sentence that still contains *cool*,  but otherwise welcome to stack exchange :)

Comment: I thought "würde" and "sein" dont go together in one sentence?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Why would you say so?