# "würde sein" statt "wäre" in Konjunktiv I?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Unser Reporter Alexander Osang war früh davon überzeugt, dass Großes von Joachim Löw und seiner Elf zu erwarten **sein würde**, und er behielt recht.

Obwohl die beiden Formen *sein würde* und *wäre* korrekt sind, wird behauptet (zum Beispiel [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/what-is-better-es-w%C3%BCrde-sein-or-es-w%C3%A4re)), dass *wäre* zu bevorzugen ist. Deshalb überrascht es mich, dass hier die Spiegel-Redaktion *sein würde* gewählt hat. Oder ist *sein würde* die anerkannte Form für den Konjunktiv I?

Comment: Könnte auch ein Konjunktiv 2 von "zu erwarten sein werden" sein. Also äquivalent zu "zu erwarten sein werden würde"

Comment: @Emanuel Danke. Glaubst du, dass das ist, was der Spiegel-Redakteur schreiben wollte?

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt keine Ahnung... ich glaube er wollte nicht "erwarten sein wird" schreiben, da das zu "indikativ" klingt (aber richtig sein kann), und er wollte aber auch nicht "wäre" schreiben, da das so nach Irrealis klingt. "sein würde" ist ein Kompromis. Was genau das jetzt ist und heißt ist zweitrangig. Weiß eh keiner so genau ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grundsätzlich gehört da aus meiner Sicht ein Konjunktiv I hin, es ist ja die Wiedergabe der Überzeugung des Reporters:

> Unser Reporter Alexander Osang war früh davon überzeugt, dass Großes von Joachim Löw und seiner Elf zu erwarten *sei*, und er behielt recht.

Die Überzeugung hat sich ja als richtig herausgestellt. Alternativ, wie schon vorgeschlagen wurde, war ursprünglich ein Futur gesagt worden:

> Unser Reporter Alexander Osang war früh davon überzeugt, dass Großes von Joachim Löw und seiner Elf zu erwarten sein *werde*, und er behielt recht.

Konjunktiv II für *sein* hat da nur etwas zu suchen, wenn sich die Annahme schlussendlich als falsch herausgestellt hat:

> Unser Reporter Alexander Osang war früh davon überzeugt, dass Großes von Joachim Löw und seiner Elf zu erwarten *wäre*, aber er lag völlig daneben.

Den Futur I kann man jedoch nicht in den Konjunktiv II setzen, denn der würde-Konjunktiv entspricht der Konstruktion eines Futur I Konjunktiv II ("Nimm das Hilfsverb und setze es in den Konjunktiv II"). Vergleiche:

> Ich werde ins Kino gehen. (Futur I Indikativ)
>   Er sagte, dass er ins Kino gehen *werde*. (Futur I Konjunktiv I)
>   Er sagte, dass er ins Kino gehen *würde*. (strukturell Futur I Konjunktiv II, real analytischer Konjunktiv II)
>   *Er sagte, dass er ins Kino gehen werden würde.
>   *Er sagte, dass er ins Kino gehen würde werden.

Halte ich für beides falsch. Der Autor hat einfach *sein* mit *würde* konjugiert, was tatsächlich sehr ungewöhnlich ist (aber grammatisch). Eventuell gab es im Original ja tatsächlich ein Futur und er ist darüber gestolpert.

Comment: Müsste ein "würde" nicht von einem "wenn" oder gleichwertigem flankiert werden, also etwa, dass er ins Kino gehen würde, wenn es aufhört zu schneien? Oder er würde, an meiner Stelle, ins Kino gehen (wenn er an meiner Stelle wäre).

Comment: In der Wiedergabe der direkten Rede kann man den Konjunktiv II verwenden, wenn der Konjunktiv I mit Indikativ Präsens zusammenfällt oder man das Wiedergegebene nicht für wahr hält.

Answer (score 1):

Früher hätte ich gesagt, wenn jemand would be mit würde sein statt wäre übersetzt, dann ist das falsches Deutsch. Heute findet man "würde sein" immer häufiger in Zeitungen und auch Romanen, das ich geradezu unsicher bin.

Nach wie vor halte ich "Das wäre schön" für richtig und "Das würde schön sein" für falsch. Und ich weiß nicht, woher die Marotte mit dem "würde sein" kommt. Ist das Einfluß des Englischen? Ich habe den Verdacht, dass manche Übersetzer von Romanen englisches would be einfach mit würde sein übersetzen.

Jedenfalls haben wir es hier mit einem Phänomen zu tun, wo man eine Veränderung des deutschen Systems vermuten könnte. Vielleicht gibt es hierzu schon genauere Studien.

Ich frage mich, wann ich höre "Wenn ich ein Vöglein sein würde" statt "Wenn ich ein Vöglein wär". Jedenfalls haben unsere Deutschlehrer uns eingebleut, im Wenn-Satz kein würde.

Comment: Zum letzten Satz: »Wenn ich arbeiten würde, wäre ich jetzt nicht zuhause.« ist meines Wissens nach schon länger allgemein als korrekt angesehen worden.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - Ja, beim Gebrauch von würde gibt es allerhand Finessen, mir geht es aber speziell um "würde sein" statt wäre.